# Получение логина и id пользователя после входа на сайт

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, сервлеты

Здравствуйте есть сервлет SignInServlet.java

```
@WebServlet(name = "SignInServlet", urlPatterns = {"/SignInServlet"})
public class SignInServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
User user;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    user = new User();
    String login = req.getParameter("login");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    String role;

    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();

    Connection conn = null;

    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/crm";
    String name = "vladimir";
    String pass = "1234";
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, pass);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result1 = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
        while (result1.next()) 
        {
            if((password.equals(result1.getString("password"))) && 
                    (login.equals(result1.getString("login"))))
            {
                user.setID(result1.getInt("iduser"));
                user.setLogin(result1.getString("login"));
                user.setUserrole(result1.getString("userrole"));
                req.setAttribute("login", login);
                req.getRequestDispatcher("/signiinsucces.jsp").
                        forward(req, resp);
            }
            /*else if((!password.equals(result1.getString("password"))) && 
                    (!login.equals(result1.getString("login"))))
            {
                getServletContext().
                        getRequestDispatcher("/signiinfail.jsp").
                        forward(req, resp);
            }*/
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        getServletContext().
                getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").
                forward(req, resp);
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (conn != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                conn.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                getServletContext().
                        getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").
                        forward(req, resp);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Есть jsp для входа на сайт

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Вход</title>
</head>



<body>
    <form action="SignInServlet">
        <p>
            Ваш логин<br>
            <input type="text" size="40" max="30" min="1" name="login">
        </p>
        <p>
            Ваш пароль<br>
            <input type="password" size="40" max="25" min="1" 
                   name="password">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Войти">
        </p>
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <p>
        <a href="index.jsp">На главную страницу</a> 
    </p>
</body>
```

После пользователь попадает на site.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Начальная страница создания сайта</title>
</head>


<body>
    <form action="SiteServlet">
        <p>
            Название сайта<br>
            <input type="text" size="40" max="30" min="1" name="sitename">
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </p>
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <p>
        <a href="signiinsucces.jsp">Назад</a> 
    </p>
</body>
```

которцю обрабатывает сервлет

```
@WebServlet(name = "SiteServlet", urlPatterns = {"/SiteServlet"})
public class SiteServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
User user;
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    try
    {
        user = new User();
        String sitename = req.getParameter("sitename");
        int id = user.getID();
        String login = user.getLogin();

        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        Connection conn = null;

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/crm";
        String name = "vladimir";
        String pass = "1234";

        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, pass);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,conn.toString());

            if(id != 0)
            {

                String insert = "insert into site values(" + id + 
                    ", '" + login + "', '" + sitename + "')";
                statement.executeUpdate(insert);
                req.getRequestDispatcher("/template.jsp").forward(req, resp);
            }
            else
            {
                req.getRequestDispatcher("/error2.jsp").forward(req, resp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            getServletContext().
                    getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").
                    forward(req, resp);
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (conn != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    conn.close();
                } 
                catch (SQLException ex) 
                {
                    getServletContext().
                            getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").
                            forward(req, resp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Как после входа пользхователя получать его логин и id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
httpSession.setAttribute("id", id);
httpSession.setAttribute("login", login);
```

Получать атрибуты будете соответственно:

```
Long id = (Long) httpSession.getAttribute("id");
String login = (String) httpSession.getAttribute(login");
```

Более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets003.htm#BNAFO).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Добавил HttpSession session = req.getSession(true); session.setAttribute("iduser", iduser);
                    session.setAttribute("loginuser", loginuser); это код в SignInServlet.java, так же код в SiteServlet.java HttpSession httpSession = req.getSession(true); int iduser = (int) httpSession.getAttribute("iduser");
            String loginuser = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("loginuser");      В итоге не работает вставка в таблицу полученных данных

Comment: @Zhuk, не в итоге, а теперь. Операция задания и получения атрибута сессии не как не связана с вставкой данных в таблицу. Вы не правильно соединяетесь с базой данных. Нужно подключаться не через `DriverManager`, а через `DataSource`.